# How to add footer that is uneditable using interop in c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, footer, office-interop

I use this code to add a footer to a word document, but I want to make the footer read-only or uneditable if opened by an application. Is this possible? I searched on the net, but there isn't mention anywhere how to make it uneditable.

```
Word.Application wordApp = null;

        // word document
        document = null;

        try
        {
            wordApp = new Word.Application();
            //WordApp.Visible = true;
            // open
            document = wordApp.Application.Documents.Open(wordpath);

            foreach (Word.Section wordSection in document.Sections)
            {
                //Get the footer range and add the footer details.
                Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
                footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdGray50;
                footerRange.Font.Size = 15;
                footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
                footerRange.Text = wordHeaderName;

            }

            // save 
            document.Save();
        }
        finally
        {
            // close excel document & application
            if (document != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    document.Close(Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
                }
                catch { }
            }

            if (wordApp != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    wordApp.Quit();
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What all in the document should be editable/not editable, and by whom, and under what circumstances?

Comment: @CindyMeister only the footer should not be editable and all user cannot edit the footer permanently. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Word (since 2007, as I recall) have a protection possiblity that allows you to block the entire document for editing - you can then explicitly *allow* editing for various ranges. The tricky part is that these ranges must have content in order for the permission to take (and remain) in effect.

This means you might need to put some "hidden text" in a header, for example, that should be editable. And if any header or footer is locked the option to unlink from previous is not available. Any missing functionality could be provided with code tools that unprotects, does whatever needs to be done, then reprotects.

On the assumption that all "parts" of the document already exist when you open the document and create a footer, change your code to something like the following.

**Notes**:

- there might be syntax "blips" as I'm converting this from VBA
- You should probably read up on document Protection in both the object
  model as well as the general Word help, especially IRM possibilities.
- You can assign a password to the protection.

Code snippet:

```
 Word.Application wordApp = null;

    // word document
    document = null;

    try
    {
        wordApp = new Word.Application();
        //WordApp.Visible = true;
        // open
        document = wordApp.Application.Documents.Open(wordpath);
        Word.Range permittedRange = document.Content;
        permittedRange.Editors.Add(Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);

        foreach (Word.Section wordSection in document.Sections)
        {
            //Allow editing the headers?
            permittedRange = wordSection.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            permittedRange.Editors.Add(Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);

            //Get the footer range and add the footer details.
            Word.Range footerRange = wordSection.Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
            footerRange.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdGray50;
            footerRange.Font.Size = 15;
            footerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            footerRange.Text = wordHeaderName;

        }
        document.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        // save 
        document.Save();
```